# Central Limit Theorem when variance and mean depend on N

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Is there  a Central limit theorem in which the variance of the random variables depends on the sample size?
For example, assume $X_1$, ..., $X_n$, $n$ independent random variables such that $E(X_i) = \mu_n$ and $V(X_i) = \sigma^2_n$, for any $i = 1$, $\dots$, $n$.

I assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n = \mu$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sigma^2_n = \sigma^2$.

What is the convergence in law of $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \mu)$, where $\bar{x}_n = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^n X_i$?

Can I say that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \mu) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2)$? If yes, could you please give a reference? This is actually slightly different from the standard central limit theorem I now, in which the mean and the variance do not depend on $n$.

An example of random variables is, $X_i = (1 + \frac{1}{n})Y_i$ where $Y_i$'s are i.i.d.

**EDIT:** For the  example $X_i = (1 + \frac{1}{n})Y_i$, I can use the standard CLT on $Y$ and then use Slutsky's lemma. But assume that I want to establish the convergence directly using a CLT. Or assume that the function is a bit more complicated than a simple product.

Comment: You might want to look at the Lyapunov and Lindeberg conditions

Comment: For your application though, you do not really need CLT for triangular arrays -- you can just use the standard CLT in combination with Slutsky's lemma.

Comment: @Henry Yes but the conditions are $E(X_i) = \mu$ and $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2$, right?

Comment: @nejimban Yes you're right. But this is just an illustration. My application is complicated than a simple product. I just updated my post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could have a look [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12263.pdf) or at earlier references.